# React Native and Drawer : undefined is not an object navigator

Tags: react-native, navigator

I want to set up a sidebar menu with Drawer (Native Base).

I have a App.js :

```
export default class ReactProject extends Component {

 renderScene (route, navigator) {
  return <route.component navigator={navigator} />
}

render() {
  return (
  <Navigator
  style={styles.container}
  renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
  initialRoute={{component: Home}}  
  />
  );
}
}
```

A Home.js with the drawer :

```
export default class Home extends Component {

    render() {   
    return (
      <Drawer
        ref={(ref) => { this._drawer = ref; }}
        content={<SideBar />} navigator={this.props.navigator}>
        <Container>
        </Container>
      </Drawer>
    );
}
}
```

And sidebar.js which is loaded into the drawer :

```
export default class SideBar extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

redirect(routeName){
    this.props.navigator.push({
      component: routeName
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Content style={styles.sidebar}>
          <ListItem button >
            <Text>Home</Text>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem button >
            <Text>Test</Text>
          </ListItem>
           <ListItem button onPress={this.redirect.bind('Blank')}>
            <Text>Blank Page</Text>
          </ListItem>
      </Content>
    );
  }
}
```

But when I click i have this error:

**Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push')**

I do not have this problem when the button is in the page but only in the sidebar.js

Could someone help me?

thank you,
Thomas.

Comment: "When the button is in the page" - do you mean when you place the button in your home.js ?

Comment: may be 'this' is not in scope of that function. change redirect function to an arrow function.

redirect = (routeName) => {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      component: routeName
    });
  }

Comment: @funkysoul : Exactly !

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change little bit code of your Home.js as per mentioned below:

```
render() {   
return (
  <Drawer
    ref={(ref) => { this._drawer = ref; }}
    content={<SideBar navigator={this.props.navigator} />}
    <Container>
    </Container>
  </Drawer>
);
```

And add this lines of code in your sidebar.js file:

```
  static propTypes = {
      navigator: React.PropTypes.object,
   }
```